# App in .net core is not redirecting to https

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

App in .net core is not redirecting to https

Good Morning. Can someone help me?
I have the following problem. My website is not automatically redirecting to HTTPS. I need to put https: // at the beginning of my application for it to work. When the session goes down or I log out, the site is directed to http instead of https.
These are the settings:

ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
         //   .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            
            );


        services.AddHealthChecks()
        .AddCheck<HealthCheck>("check_smc_app",
            failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded,
            tags: new[] { "smc_tag" });


        services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
        //services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
            //options.HttpsPort = 8080;
        });
       

        InjetorDependencias.Registrar(services);
        var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new MappingEntidades());
        });
        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/v1/health/live");
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/v1/health/read");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have https_port defined in appsetting.json?

Comment: Looks good to me. Where is it hosted? Is the server rejecting HTTP outright and not letting the request fall through for the application to handle?

Answer (score 0):

In development env, application is by default http. if you want to use https for development, use ngrok or you can check the port which is mentioned in launchsettings.json file in Properties directory of your project.for the production, it depends on your cloud but if you want to install SSL to IIS this article is good way to go.
https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-install/microsoft-iis-7-ssl-installation/

Comment: Actually, new ASP.NET Core projects default to including local development HTTPS and include HTTPS redirect. It installs local development certificates.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not defined the https port. Per the documentation you need something like the following in appsettings.json

```
{
    "https_port": 443,
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Of course, if you want a different port for development you could override this value in appsettings.development.json. For that matter, you can override the port in a variety of ways.

I also believe that you do not need this in your code

```
    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
        //options.HttpsPort = 8080;
    });
```

The documentation is here: [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)